# Regex for Detecting Pincode and Mobile number separately

Tags: python, regex

I want to make a regex that can detect pincode and mobile number in an Indian address. The problem I faced is that it is taking first 6 digits of mobile number as pincode. So, want to make a regex that can detect both indian pincode of 6 digits and mobile number separately.

Can anybody help me out?

Thanks in Advance.

BTW, I searched over google and found these regex but is there any way I can combine these so that it can detect both pincode and mobile number separately.

- Pincode --> `([1-9]{1}[0-9]{5}|[1-9]{1}[0-9]{3}\\s[0-9]{3})`
- Mobile Number --> `^(?:(?:\+|0{0,2})91(\s*[\-]\s*)?|[0]?)?[789]\d{9}|(\d[-]?){10}\d$`

Comment: You can combine two expressions using an or `|` and you can make sure that a pin number isn't detected in a mobile number by matching the end of a string `$`.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Please provide some sample data to work with.

Comment: `{1}` is an inherently redundant quantifier, and `[-]`/`[\-]` are equivalent to just `-`. Try adding `^` to the beginning and `$` to the end of your pincode pattern.